# Enviar un embed en Discord.PY

Tags: python, discord.py

Bien, quisiera enviar un embed a un canal de Discord cada vez que un usuario boostee el servidor. Para ello, uso el evento on_message que proporciona la API de Discord.PY. Actualmente lo único que hago es una verificación del tipo de mensaje el cual envía Discord por defecto al canal de boosts. Quisiera que el bot envie a ese canal un embed.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "MessageType.premium_guild" in str(message.type):
        await message.channel.send("Gracias por boostear")
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo, tienes que comprobar que el tipo del mensaje es del tipo `premium_guild_subscription`. Con una condicional que verifique que `message.type` es igual que [`discord.MessageType.premium_guild_subscription`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageType.premium_guild_subscription). Una vez eso verificado, debes inicializar una variable que contenga un embed.

Ejemplo claro de inicializacion de un embed:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Boost", description="Un usuario ha boosteado el servidor", color=0x00ff00)
embed.add_field(name="Test", value="Test")
await message.channel.send(embed)
```

Para mas info sobre embeds, visita [la documentacion oficial de Discord.PY](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)